# Creating checkbox field on custom post type metabox

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on the following code. How can I can create and save a checkbox as a custom field in Custom Post Type?

```
function render_metas( $post )
{
    $we_productMetas = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $onSale = isset( $we_productMetas['onSale_box'] ) ? esc_attr( $we_productMetas['onSale_box'][0] ) : '';
?>

<input type="checkbox" class=""  name="onSale_box" id="onSale-box" value="<?php echo $onSale; ?>" />


<?php
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'we_metas_save' );
function we_metas_save( $post_id )
{
if( isset( $_POST['onSale_box'] ) ){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'onSale_box', wp_kses( $_POST['onSale_box'], $allowed ) );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 function render_metas( $post )
    {
        $onSale = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'onSale_box',true );
    ?>
    <input <?php checked($onSale,'yes',true); ?> type="checkbox" class=""  name="onSale_box" id="onSale-box" value="yes" />
    <?php
    }
    add_action( 'save_post', 'we_metas_save' );
    function we_metas_save( $post_id )
    {
        $new_value = isset( $_POST['onSale_box']) ?  $_POST['onSale_box'] : "no";
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'onSale_box', $new_value );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Tuấn Phương but how about saving it?

Comment: but after I update the page the checkbox is still unchecked

Comment: well now the checkbox is always checked! I unchecked the checkbox and update but after refreshing checkbox is still checked!

Comment: ah Should remove condition. because when you uncheck $_POST['onSale_box'] is NULL

Comment: still showing the checkbox always checked even after unchecking and updaing

Comment: I thinks so because I am getting other custom Field but not checkbox updated value